# How to reset ListBox SelectedItem to it's orginal state. WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 ListBox with 2 items, "Line 1" and "Line 2".  When I select an item, it will change the selected items state to selected and the text will be red.

After the selection I display a MessageBox, then select OK, and return to the ListBox where the item is still selected (red).

How do I reset the selected item to it's original state?

TIA,
Trey

This is the code I'm using.   It is a bit of a hack but kinda works.

```
 private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Line 1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found");
                ResetListBox();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
                ResetListBox();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void ResetListBox()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Line 1");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Line 2");
    }
```

Comment: If you got only two items you can use something else than listbox

Comment: myListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MVVM, then the ViewModel could take control of this Logic, clearing the selection after the user clicks Ok on the Messagebox. The code might look something like

```
public void Show()
{
     MessageBox.Show();
     SelectedCustomer = _previouslySelectedCustomer;
}
```

The property will Raise property changes and your list's SelectedItem property bound to it, that way the changes will get reflected in the UI.

If you're not using MVVM, then it will look something similar except that you would have to set it in Codebehind.

Hope this helps

Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

store the previous selected item. After showing the messagebox, reset the selected item manually on the listbox